# 'Case' inside another value condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a CASE inside another CASE expression. Actually, the situation is:

```
 (SELECT cmp_tubo 
 FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_serra
 WHERE res_tubo_serra.cod_ordem_producao = ro.cod_ordem_producao AND res_tubo_serra.idc_tubo = ro.idc_tubo
 AND res_tubo_serra.idc_serra != 0
 ) AS cmp_corte_ponta
```

What I need:

IF the value of "cmp_corte_ponta" = 0 THEN I'll need to do this search and replace the value of the "cmp_corte_ponta":

```
   Select 
    (CASE serra.tip_corte
     WHEN '1'   THEN to_char(SERRA.CMP_CORTE)
     ELSE 'NO'
     END
    ) cmp_corte_ponta
    from fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra
```

IF the value of "cmp_corte_ponta" != 0, then the value must still the same.

What kind of syntax should I use?

Thx!

*** EDITED CODE ***

```
select 
  pla.cod_pedido,
  pla.cod_aqa,

 coalesce (
 NULLIF(
 (SELECT cmp_tubo 
            FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_serra
            WHERE res_tubo_serra.cod_ordem_producao = ro.cod_ordem_producao
                AND res_tubo_serra.idc_tubo = ro.idc_tubo
                AND res_tubo_serra.idc_serra != 0)
    , 0),
    (SELECT
        (CASE serra.tip_corte
             WHEN '1'   THEN SERRA.CMP_CORTE
             ELSE 0
        END)
    FROM fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra)) as cmp_corte_ponta,

  pla.another_collum
 FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_secao_od ro...
```

And the error now is:

"ORA-01427 - "single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Comment: what is `ro` here? I don't see that alias in either statement and it feels very relevant. That being said, it's totally legal to nest `CASE` expressions inside of each other like `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <resultx> ELSE <resulty> END WHEN <condition> THEN <resultz> END`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ORIGINAL** but messed up datatypes:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
    NULLIF(
        (SELECT cmp_tubo 
            FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_serra
            WHERE res_tubo_serra.cod_ordem_producao = ro.cod_ordem_producao
                AND res_tubo_serra.idc_tubo = ro.idc_tubo
                AND res_tubo_serra.idc_serra != 0)
    , 0),
    SELECT
        (CASE serra.tip_corte
             WHEN '1'   THEN to_char(SERRA.CMP_CORTE)
             ELSE 'NO'
        END) cmp_corte_ponta
    FROM fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra
)
```

**EDIT** corrected datatypes. `NULLIF()` and `COALESCE()` both need all argument types to be the same (perhaps coercion will take place):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
    NULLIF(
        (SELECT to_char(cmp_tubo)
            FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_serra
            WHERE res_tubo_serra.cod_ordem_producao = ro.cod_ordem_producao
                AND res_tubo_serra.idc_tubo = ro.idc_tubo
                AND res_tubo_serra.idc_serra != 0)
    , '0'),
    SELECT
        (CASE serra.tip_corte
             WHEN '1'   THEN to_char(SERRA.CMP_CORTE)
             ELSE 'NO'
        END) cmp_corte_ponta
    FROM fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra
)
```

Comment: @Barbaros well the docs say there is a ```NULLIF()``` function in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions107.htm#SQLRF00681

Comment: Exactly, thank you so much, I never met so far, even as an Oracle man :) +1

Comment: I tried that way, but it generate an error saying that: "ORA-00932. expected NUMBER got CHAR. I replace 'NO' for '0' but still finding an error.

Comment: What datatype is ```cmp_corte```? Why dou you need to apply ```to_char()``` on it? ```COALESCE()``` needs arguments of the same datatype. If you want to get this ```'NO'``` you probably need to "charify" ```cmp_tubo``` as well (don't forget to change the second parameter of ```NULLIF``` to ```'0'``` as well). I gonna edit my answer

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to your question, pls? With the error.

Comment: Pls perform just the 2 subselects inside the ```COALESCE``` each on its own. Is at least one of it giving you more than one row? I guess you need some ```WHERE``` condition in the second subselect perhaps?

Comment: When I run just the 2 subselects, it generate an error "ORA-00936: missing expression" at line 9 (line 9 is the SELECT before the CASE expression)

Comment: You need to run them on their own, not together. ```SELECT``` should be line 1 in both queries

Answer (score 0):

I might try some nested decode statements given the small amount of values you are dealing with:

```
 (SELECT decode(cmp_tubo, 
                0, (SELECT decode(serra.tip_corte, 
                                  '1', to_char(serra.cmp_corte),
                                  'NO')
                    FROM fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra),
                cmp_tubo)
 FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_serra
 WHERE res_tubo_serra.cod_ordem_producao = ro.cod_ordem_producao AND res_tubo_serra.idc_tubo = ro.idc_tubo
 AND res_tubo_serra.idc_serra != 0
 ) AS cmp_corte_ponta
```